# Can't install CA certificate

Tags: certificates

We're trying to set up a new VPN infrastructure and have hit a roadblock with Android. For some reason we are unable to install the corporate CA that's issued the VPN server certs.

My LineageOS 18.1 (Android 11) test device says "Failed to install certificate" if I try installing with Certificate Installer from the file store. It says nothing at all if I try to install from within the Settings app.

System logs give me this parse error, which makes no sense. This is the same PEM-encoded X.509 certificate used with no problems in almost 100 Linux servers as well as Windows, macOS, and iOS VPN clients:

```
03-17 09:33:07.388  3319  3338 I MediaProvider: Using lower FS for /storage/emulated/0/Download/r1_root_ca.crt
03-17 09:33:07.400  1046  1764 I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {cmp=com.android.certinstaller/.CertInstaller (has extras)} from uid 10113
03-17 09:33:07.403   577   577 I android.hardware.power-service-qti: Power setMode: 5 to: 1
03-17 09:33:07.414  1046  1764 W ActivityTaskManager: Tried to set launchTime (0) < mLastActivityLaunchTime (1416012)
03-17 09:33:07.437  8437  8437 D CredentialHelper: # extras: 1
03-17 09:33:07.437  8437  8437 D CredentialHelper:    CERT: 2706
03-17 09:33:07.438  8437  8437 W CredentialHelper: parseCert(): java.security.cert.CertificateException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0000be:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_TAG
03-17 09:33:07.440  8437  8437 D CertInstaller: Attempting credentials installation, has ca cert? false, has user cert? false
```

Are there any special requirements that Android has for CA certificates that I'm not aware of? Are there particular certificate elements that cause problems?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out; we have always left the full OpenSSL output in the certificate file, secure in the knowledge that clients would only parse the contents between `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`.

Apparently Android is the exception to this rule. We removed all the human-readable data, and the certificate was processed successfully.